# Allow Xamarin.Form's CarouselPage to show edge of other content

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

Is it possible in Xamarin.Forms to have some sort of "peek" on other contents of the CarouselPage like this one from Spotify? To let the user know that there are other stuff if you swipe.

[image]

Comment: Lala,  Where you able to find a solution to your question? I have the same question and wondering how you solved it?